Is there a way to flatten a nested JSON in Azure Data Factory without using Dataflows?
I'm using Azure Data Factory copy statements to grab the output of an API as a JSON file and drop the data into a synapse data warehouse. The JSON has a layout similar to the JSON added below, though the 'values' field can have a length of over 10,000 characters. I've added a table below that has what I hope the output should look like as well.
I do have one limitation in that I am unable to use dataflows. I understand this is the usual method for working through this issue, but it is not a solution I am specifically capable of using, which is why I am asking here for any alternative solution.
Any and all help is appreciated.
JSON
{
     "records": [
          {
               "id": 1,
               "name": "name1",
               "values": [
                    {
                    "id":20987,
                    "value": "value1"
                    },
                    {
                    "id":94756,
                    "value": "value2"
                    },
                    {
                    "id":63009,
                    "value": "value3"
                    }
               ]
          },
          {
               "id": 2,
               "name": "name2",
               "values": [
                    {
                    "id":227272727272,
                    "value": "value7",
                    "user": "Greg"
                    },
                    {
                    "id":456787654664,
                    "value": "value8", 
                    "user": "Tony"
                    },
                    {
                    "id":283749467394,
                    "value": "value9", 
                    "user": "Maria"
                    }
               ]
          }
     ]
}

SQL



id
name
values.id
values.value
values.user




1
name1
20987
value1
NULL


1
name1
94756
value2
NULL


1
name1
63009
value3
NULL


2
name2
227272727272
value7
Greg


2
name2
456787654664
value8
Tony


2
name2
283749467394
value9
Maria




In order to flatten Json without using dataflow, you can use SQL query script. Below is the approach.

Take the lookup activity and take the Json dataset in that activity.

Take the copy activity and connect it sequentially with lookup activity. In source , give the below query.


DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max) = N'@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].records}';
SELECT
   r.id,r.name,v.id AS [values.id],
    v.value AS [values.value]
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
        id INT,
        name VARCHAR(50),
   [values] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
  
    ) AS r
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.[values]) WITH (
        id VARchar(100),
        value VARCHAR(50)
    ) AS v;


In sink, give the azure sql table as sink dataset.

This will make sure the Json is flattened and copied to the SQL table.
Note: your data is not having relational data. user field is missing for id=1; We can only flatten the relational data here. Make sure the data structure is same across all the lineitems.

User field is intentionally missing as it is not present in all values arrays. Additionally it seems I can not use a REST API in lookup activities. I'll see if the API I am using can be switched to HTTP, if I can not then this won't work for me.
Also, I'll see if I need the additional columns in value so I can ignore them. I have records that also have a blank array for values, so if I can't get around needing perfect uniformity then this won't work for me.

I'm also not seeing how I can make the lookup output the source of the copy data activity, how do I go about that? Do I build a new sql source or something to that effect?

Since you are going to copy the data to synapse data warehouse, you can use the same dataset for source also. Select query option and give the query in the query text box.
